# Read Data from GPS device

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, gps

I am building a location tracking system for one of our client. They have GPS devicees installed in vehicles and each device has programmed with a server IP and a port number. GPS device communicate on given IP address and port. I would like to read the packet comes from GPS device (like latitude, longitude and other information, as packet contains information in binary) without doing any read operation.

What i am looking for :

A. Read data from Device and store in some intermediate location, since we have TCP listener by which Device communicate with us.

B. I don't want to do any operation, as simple as that whatever or any format data, if GPS device sent to listener, it must listen ans store it, without any manipulation.

Thanks

Comment: Actually there are many devices which send data in different different format, what i am looking for without identifying the device and its format, i want to store it in intermediate location, since i don't want to do any operation on data packet to identifying start character and terminating character. I am looking to simply store the data in respect of any kind of format.

Comment: have you managed to solve this ? if so please share the outcomes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [code](http://www.gano.name/shawn/GpsInspector/) might help you.

Comment: Thanks Hassan, let me see how this code works, but please read my first comment which i gave to npinti, it might clear you what i am looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I provide sample code for it check:

```
public class ServerListener {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ServerListener().startServer();
}

public void startServer() {
    final ExecutorService clientProcessingPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(03);

    Runnable serverTask = new Runnable() {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5094);
                System.out.println("Waiting for clients to connect...");
                while (true) {
                    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                    clientProcessingPool.submit(new ClientTask(clientSocket));
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Unable to process client request");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    Thread serverThread = new Thread(serverTask);
    serverThread.start();
}

private class ClientTask implements Runnable {
    private final Socket clientSocket;

    private ClientTask(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Got a client !");
        while (true) {

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            String clientData = "";

            clientData = reader.readLine();
            System.out.println("clientdata::::"+clientData);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }


 }
}
```